# Spring Data, MVC DomainClassConverter how to get to id from request and keep using domain type as param

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data

As part of Spring Data, there is `DomainClassConverter` which helps with repository lookups so that we don't have to do lookup manually.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.basic.domain-class-converter

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders/{id}")
public class PaymentController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/payment", method = PUT)
    ResponseEntity<?> submitPayment(@PathVariable("id") Order order) {

        if (order == null) {
            throw new OrderNotFoundException(???orderId???);
        }

        ...

    }   
}
```

How can I get to **{id}** from request without changing ***Order*** parameter to ***Long***?
DomainClassConverter converts **{id}** to null as expected

My intention is to use order id in `OrderNotFoundException`

Answer (score 0):

I can think of couple of ways.
 1. Change the method to

```
   @RequestMapping(path = "/payment", method = PUT)
    ResponseEntity<?> submitPayment(@PathVariable("id") Order order, HttpServletRequest request) {


     String path = request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE).toString()
     // path will have "/payment/id". use substring or something similar to get just id

}
```

2. Write a `@Around` Aspect for @RequestMapping and get the argument

   ```
   @Aspect
   @Configuration
   public class ControllerAspect {

            @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
       public void requestMapping() {}

       @Around("requestMapping()")
       public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
           String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
           String path = (String) joinPoint.getArgs()[0];

           Object result=  joinPoint.proceed();

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi pvpkiran, thanks for suggestions. How would you implement @Around aspect? Could you give me an example?